# Não consigo criar segunda atividade

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consigo criar uma nova atividade no Android Studio, aparece a mensagem "Package name is not a valid package name"

Comment: A mensagem diz que seu package está inválido. Faça um teste: colocando o package como:    com.exemplo.meuapp

Answer (score 0):

Os pacotes tem que ter no mínimo um ".". o nome de pacote que colocaste "layout" não tem o ".". Podes usar layout.projeto por ex., ou qualquer nome que contenha ".". No android, aconselha-se  a nomear pacotes, com um nome de dominio invertido para identificar quem desenvolveu. por ex: "br.com.microsoft" é um bom nome de pacote, se foi a microsoft que tivesse desenvolvido o app. No teu caso, poderia ser: "br.com.alexandrelima". Estes nomes são só identificadores de pacote, não estão vinculados a necessidade de existência de sites com o mesmo nome.